# Sublime text Less build package not compiling to css

Tags: less, sublimetext2, sublimetext

i'm using sublime text the best text editor i have ever used, but i am having an issue with it right now, initially i developed on windows but now i have moved to using ubuntu 14.04 lts, i have successfully installed sublime text 2 but am having some issues compiling my LESS files like i usually do with sublime test on windows (ctrl+b) LOL. This is serious. This is the erro i get any time i try to compile.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'lessc', u'/opt/lampp/htdocs/r6images/public/assets/css/sitePages.less', u'/opt/lampp/htdocs/r6images/public/assets/css/sitePages.css', u'--verbose']]
[dir:  /opt/lampp/htdocs/r6images/public/assets/css]
[path:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
[Finished]
```

Would really appreciate by voting up a right answer thanks!

Comment: do you have `lessc` installed?

Comment: This is so embarrassing, lessc wasn't installed, got it working now though, installed lessc and it works like a charm!